# ThreeJS: Instantiating an object sets its position to zero?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having a bit of trouble with ThreeJS/Javascript in general. I've got a Player class, and a Bullet class. When the player class' "shooting" variable is true, it creates bullets, adds them to an array, and updates each bullet. The problem im running into is that instead of the bullets appearing where the player is, they always appear at worldspace 0,0,0

Here's the player class

```
var Player = function()
{

    this.lives = 3;
    this.upgrade = 0;
    this.bullets = [];
    this.shooting = false;

    //width, height, depth, health
    NPC.call(this, 50, 100, 50, 100);

    this.update = function()
    {
        if (this.shooting)
        {

            var b = new Bullet(this.position.clone() , new THREE.Vector3(0, 5, 0));
            scene.add(b);
            player.bullets.push(b);
            console.log(this.position);
            console.log(b.position);
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++)
        {
            this.bullets[i].update();

        }



    };





};



Player.prototype = Object.create(NPC.prototype);
```

Here's the bullet class

```
var Bullet = function(position, velocity)
{
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = velocity;


    this.geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5, 5, 5);
    this.material =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});

    THREE.Mesh.call(this, this.geometry, this.material);


    this.update = function()
    {
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
        this.position.z += this.velocity.z;
    };



};

Bullet.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
Bullet.prototype.constructor = Bullet;
```

and here's the output of the console every update, the first being the player's position, and the second being the bullet's position. Every bullet's position starts at zero

> THREE.Vector3 {x: 101.62018337285986, y: -87.19228026722121, z: 99.99999999999977, constructor: function, set: function…}
>   THREE.Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, constructor: function, set: function…}

Comment: Okay, i fixed it by applying its position after creating it in the player class, instead of setting it inside of the Bullet class. Can someone explain what exactly i was doing before?

Comment: Tip: You may want to do this instead: `this.position.copy( position )`. There is a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the three.js `Mesh` constructor here:

```
THREE.Mesh.call(this, this.geometry, this.material);
```

This constructor, among other things, sets `position` to a new `0,0,0` vector. Since you call the constructor *after* you set `position` yourself, it gets reset to the default.

Just move the constructor call to the top. While we're at it, you also don't have to set `this.geometry` and `this.material` - the constructor will do it for you. In general, do your own customizations after calling the superclass constructor - otherwise, they might get overwritten.

Comment: thanks! I cant accept that until 4 minutes, so please excuse me if i do forget ;_;

Comment: Also, I did not know that geometry and material were the names of the Mesh class's properties, i was just giving them a name for myself lol